# ReactJS, CSS and SVG animations, and re-rendering

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg

The issue can be seen in action here:
https://codepen.io/fsabe/pen/opEVNR?editors=0110

On first load, you'll see the blue circle going around and the red box fading out and in.
The circle is animated via  svg tag and the box via css animations.
If you click anywhere on the canvas, the code triggers a re-render, which can be verified by opening the console.

My expectation would be for both animations to reset on click, however that does not happen.
I have a hunch that this has something to do with caching and react's shadow DOM.

Why's this happening? How to fix it?

The code is the following:

```css
#nonSvgBox {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: fade;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```js
class Component extends React.Component {
  onClick() {
    this.setState({a: 1});
  }

  render() {
    console.log('rendering');
    return (
      <div onClick={() => this.onClick()}>
        <svg>
          <path 
            stroke="blue"
            strokeWidth="10"
            fill="transparent"
            d="M50 10 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 -80"
            strokeDasharray="251.2,251.2">
            <animate
              attributeType="css"
              attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
              from="0" to="251.2" dur="1s" />
          </path>
        </svg>
        <div id="nonSvgBox"></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Component />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

React is reusing the elements, therefore the animations won't replay b/c they've already played for the current elements.

I think it's easier to resort to dom operations in this situation, versus some `setState` trickery.

https://codepen.io/guanzo/pen/vpdPzX?editors=0110

Store the refs to the 2 elements, then trigger the animations with JS.

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  onClick() {
    this.svgAnimate.beginElement()//triggers animation
    this.square.style.animation = 'none';//override css animation
    this.square.offsetHeight; /* trigger reflow */
    this.square.style.animation = null; //fallback to css animation
  }

    render() {
    console.log('rendering');
        return (
            <div onClick={() => this.onClick()}>
                <svg>
                    <path 
                        stroke="blue"
            strokeWidth="10"
                        fill="transparent"
                        d="M50 10 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 -80"
            strokeDasharray="251.2,251.2">
              <animate
                ref={(svgAnimate) => { this.svgAnimate = svgAnimate; }} 
                attributeType="css"
                attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
                from="0" to="251.2" dur="1s" />
                </path>
              </svg>
        <div id="nonSvgBox"
          ref={(square) => { this.square = square; }} 
          ></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Component />, document.getElementById('app'));
```